# Error Ambiguity and Missing partial modifier

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I just follow this http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=585
to do the project but have error ambiguity and missing partial modifier.

My code at Iservice1.cs

```
namespace WCT_DataServiceApp
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ImageEmployee GetEmpByEmpNo(int EmpNo);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ImageEmployee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int EmpNo { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public byte[] EmpImage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and code at Service1.svc.cs

```
namespace WCT_DataServiceApp
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public ImageEmployee GetEmpByEmpNo(int EmpNo)
        {
            var Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=yeo-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=image;Integrated Security=True");
            Conn.Open();
            var Cmd = new SqlCommand();
            Cmd.Connection = Conn;
            Cmd.CommandText = "Select * from ImageEmployee where EmpNo=@EmpNo";
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpNo", EmpNo);

            var Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

            ImageEmployee objImgEmp = new ImageEmployee();

            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                objImgEmp.EmpNo = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["EmpNo"]);
                objImgEmp.EmpImage = (byte[])Reader["EmpImage"];
            }
            Reader.Close();
            Conn.Close();
            return objImgEmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you already has class `Service1` in your solution. If you are trying it in a new WCF project then by default you will get two files one for interface and one for class, named as: `IService1.cs` and `Service1.cs`. You need to delete these two or replace their code with yours. The error is asking you to use the word partial, which is used for Partial class as it is assuming that you are defining a partial class `Service1` in a new code file.

Comment: I find out the reason already. I should not add one more linq to sql inside my project.that is the reason i am having two class. Thank you.